# Are these two equivalent for a discrete distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In case of a discrete probability distribution and for a random variable $X$,
Is $P[X=x] = P[x-1<X<x]$?

Comment: Uhm... No. I wager that if $X$ is concentrated on $\Bbb N$, then $P[n-1<X<n]=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true. If you have that $X$ can take the values 1 until 5 all with probability 0.2, then $\mathbb{P}(X = 2) = 0.2$ but $\mathbb{P}(1 < X < 2) = 0$.

It does not even hold when you write $\mathbb{P}(x-1 < X \leq x)$. If we have an $X$ with $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = 0.25$, $\mathbb{P}(X = 1.5) = 0.5$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = 2) = 0.25$, then:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(0.5 < X \leq 1.5) = 0.75 \neq \mathbb{P}(X = 1.5).
\end{align*}